# FirefoxDriver() does not accept ProfilesIni instance as argument

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm following the example on this page to set up a custom profile to use:

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

However in my code I'm getting "Remove argument to match Firefox driver" error:

```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("testProfile");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile); // does not like myprofile as an argument here
```

Thanks

UPDATE

I was able to resolve this issue by slightly modifying try-catch's solution:

```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("testProfile"); //added this

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProfile(myprofile);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the API docs of [`FirefoxDriver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html) there's no `FirefoxDriver(ProfilesIni)` signature and `ProfilesIni` has no base class nor implements an interface that is available as a constructor signature to `FirefoxDriver`.

Through there's a `FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions)` signature. And `FirefoxDriver` has a [`setProfile(FirefoxProfile profile)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) method.

This should work:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(profile.getProfile("testProfile"));

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```